# How to uninstall Tizen wearable service app?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I have a UI app and a service app as [this tutorial](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/creating-native-service-tizen-wearables-part-2-service-launcher) specifies, a multi UI launcher and a service app. But when I relaunch the app from the IDE it says error of a app already installed with the current service app identifier.

But I do not see any way to update that service app or uninstall it. I tried following command on command line and shell window but it says `sdb` command is not found.

```
sdb uninstall org.example.myservice
```

So what is the proper way of uninstalling a service app?

**Update Solution:**

it was solved after resetting the device emulator. It could reinstall service app. But I do not know how to solve `sdb` command not found.

Answer (score 2):

After SDK installation, sdb.exe will place at the tizen C:\tizen-studio\tools or ~/tizen-studio/tools.Go to this folder, and, use it.

If you add this path to your path variables, you can use it anywhere.